# is there a set implementation with less than O(n) space

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose I want to implement a Set structure. support
1 .`add` operation to add an element into the set
2. `exist` operation to check an element is in the set.
(no data lose is allowed and no assumption about the data. You can think them as random generated number with a very lang range)

I know some implementation can achive O(1) time complexity and O(n) space complexity. If I can tolerate higher time complexity, is there a implementation with less than O(n) space complexity?

Comment: You want a `Set` implementation that looses information when data is being added? Please [edit] your question to include a much more detailed description of what you are trying to do or what the problem is.

Comment: I sometimes use interval trees. That is, the set is implemented as a binary search tree of set element intervals [start element, count] that are split/merged as needed.

Comment: A set already stores unique elements. You would have to be more specific about what you are storing in your set to get a better answer. For example, if you want a set that stores a range of elements, it is definitely possible to only keep track of either ends of the range, rather than each element of the range.

Comment: there is no assumption about the data stored in the set. You can think them as random generated number

Comment: Seems like part of the question could be rephrased as "How can I compress data losslessly?" As for whether or not an implementation of a compressed set exists, I doubt it. Usually sets are used in part for performance. Storing them compressed heavily sacrifices that performance. (Also, note that not all data can actually be compressed. Your stipulation that the items could be random numbers means that it's unlikely the data could be compressed.)

Comment: Your question displays symptoms of the [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You may need to ask a new question based on the actual problem you were facing in the first place. A set without an `add` operation is simply the empty set

Comment: "is there a implementation with less than O(n) space complexity?" No.

Comment: It is **mathematically** impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirement of less than O(n) space looks nonsensical — you have to store information on all the stuff you have inserted to support your queries.

What you can actually implement depends on which requirements you can sacrifice.

> A previous version of this answer contained the idea of using [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), but its space complexity is also O(n), so no, this is not a useful solution.

Comment: It's misleading to say a bloom filter has O(1) space complexity, since for any given error rate the space used is O(n). If you fix the size of the bloom filter, the false positive rate quickly goes to 100% as n increases (a load factor of 3 already gives you a false positive rate of at least 99.5%).